# Populate a three dimensional array vector JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a three dimensional array that represents a **game Board**. A traditional 2D for lines and columns and a third dimension because each cell can be a **stack**. SOmething like this:

```
[[[#],[b,#],[b,w,b,b,b,#],[b,#],[b,w,w,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,#],[b,b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,b,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,b,#],[b,#]],[[b,#],[b,#],[w,w,w,#],[b,b,w,w,#],[b,w,#]],[[b,#],[b,b,b,b,#],[b,w,b,#],[b,w,#],[b,b,#]]]
```

I've already parsed and now it represents my **board** variable. 
Then I did this:

```
this.stacks = [];
gameBoard.prototype.loadTiles = function(board){

    this.tiles = [];
    for(var i=0; i<board.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            var stack = board[i][j];
            var player = board[i][j].slice(-1)[0];
            this.stacks.push(stack);
        }

    }
    this.createTiles(this.stacks);
};
```

And now my **this.stacks** is a vector with all my stacks. 
The thing is, I need to create the **tiles**, the things that form the stack, like poker chips!So I did something like this:

```
gameBoard.prototype.createTiles = function(tiles) {
    for(var i=0; i<tiles.length; i++) {
        var stack = tiles[i];
        for(var j=0; j< stack.length; j++) {
            var type = stack[j];
            //console.log("TYPE" + type);
            var player = stack[stack.length - 1];
            //console.log("PLAYER" + player);
            this.stackPiles = this.createTile(type, this.scene, i*6 + j+100, player);

        }
    }
```

And here's the problem I think. I need to call a **display function** on my tiles, but I need them grouped by lines, columns and stacks to fill my 5x5 matrix properly:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++) {
        this.matrix[i] = new Array(5);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < this.matrix.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < this.matrix.length; j++) {
            //this.matrix[i][j] = new gamePiece(scene, 1 + i*this.matrix.length + j);
        }
    }
```

How do I do that. How do I create the tiles from every element on my stacks array and then put them on my 2D matrix in order to call the display function on (again) every element?

Thank you, 
Regards

Comment: Can you clarify the question? JavaScript doesn't "display" stuff. Are you using jQuery, Angular, React, Vanilla JS to show your board? You need to provide that code - even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, this is WEBGL so it is just a display function not really relevant to the topic

Comment: Actually it is. If you provide only a spotlight into your code, you can't expect a qualified answer. The minimum what is needed to to specify "this is my display function signature". Add what you tried and why it failed

Comment: I'm asking about take a 3D dimensional array, create tiles with each element of it then reassemble that back again on a matrix. Why is the display function important?

Comment: Because your code examples do not make ANY sense. SO rules suggest: provide a (working) example paired down to the exact problem - or complete code. You want help, don't let others guessing